# Automatically creating $belongsTo related Models in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two related Models, *Foo* and *Bar*, where *Bar* `$belongsTo` *Foo*. Now every *Foo* must have a *Bar*, i.e. both must be created at the same time. Using CakePHP's modeling system, is there a way for a *Bar* to be automatically created whenever a *Foo* is created (perhaps through a `saveAll()`) or should I instead write that functionality into `Foo::afterSave()`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep - just use build your data for both Foo and Bar, then `saveAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673664/dave)'s answer.

If your database table supports transactions, typically `InnoDB storage engine` in MySql. You can also tell Cake to attempt to save both records in one go. If one fails, the other one is reverted. You need to pass `array('atomic' => true)` as a second parameter to `saveAll()`

```
$this->ModelName->saveAll($this->request->data, array("atomic" => true));
```

From [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

```
atomic: If true (default), will attempt to save all records in a single transaction. 
Should be set to false if database/table does not support transactions.
```